# open cart how to get current customer info?

Tags: php, opencart

I have created following controller:

```
class ControllerCommonTestSMS extends Controller
{
    function index()
    {
       //  action
    }
}
```

But if I add the following line, it throws an error that the function is undefined:

```
$this->customer->isLogged();
```

Comment: Where did you add this line? Admin or frontend ? Does everything works fine without the customer login check?

Comment: @rusly He has not a problem to access the controller (and it's index action), he has a problem to check whether the customer is logged in. Your comment is useless...

Comment: As @SankarV is asking - are You talking about the frontend or backend (administration) controller? On **frontend** You may call `$this->customer->isLogged();` while at **backend** You may only call `$this->user->isLogged();`...

Comment: Well, I do not know how did I help... Can You please explain whether You are in administration or on frontend and what exactly do You want to achieve? Anyway, if Your problem is solved with my comment, I can write it to an answer so that You can accept it.

Comment: I was in the backend and tried to get the info of the frontend user...yes write it

Answer (score -2):

```
class ControllerCommonTestSMS extends Controller
{
    function index()
    {
       if (!$this->customer->isLogged()) {

        //code to be execu

        }
    }
}
```

this is working fine.

Comment: The OP specifically said the calling this method throws an error. Saying it works for you is not an answer, instead please describe *why* and under what circumstance it "works".